# What is the suggested date format to use in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've seen a few variations of writing dates in SQL Server as it doesn't support the more standard literal format of:

```
DATE '2014-01-01'
```

Is there a suggested way to write date-literals (or the closest thing to it) in SQL Server? Currently what I do is:

```
CAST('2014-01-01' AS date)
```

Whenever I want to use a date. Is this the most common?

Comment: The safest and most concise format you should always use is ISO standard "YYYYMMDD"

Comment: I prefer `CAST('2014-01-01' AS date)`. With the newer date time datatypes this is unambiguous though unfortunately not with the legacy datetime types. AFAIK this is actually ISO not yyyymmdd

Comment: As Martin says, `yyyy-MM-dd` is both easier to read and works perfectly fine with the new types, but not with the most common types (`[small]datetime`). For date only, `yyyyMMdd` is the only safe format. See [this dba question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/166771/1186) and more generally [Dating Reponsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates).

Comment: “For example, the 6th day of the 1st month of the year 2009 may be written as "2009-01-06" in the extended format or simply as "20090106" in the basic format without ambiguity. “ , General principles ..https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: @lptr. Thanks, so they are both ISO format then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server supports some date formats, but you can use '20220101'

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1([date]  date)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t1 values ('20220101')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM t1
> ```
>
> ```
> | date       |
> | :--------- |
> | 2022-01-01 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=98d6ef39bddaa4b34a9da068d9b9151d)*

You are misunderstanding SQL for TSQL.

In your  `SELECT date, '20220101' FROM t1`the second is a string for SQL.

But as you see in the query below, TSQL will converts the text into a date automatically when comparing for example

> ```
> SELECT CASE WHEN CAST('2014-01-01' AS date) > '20220101' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | FaLSE            |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=89e160705d7bc06c267eec5eab8cc322)*

Comment: right, but note that it doesn't work as a literal, doing `'20220101'` gives me varchar(8), though of course it properly casts to a typed column as shown in the example.

Comment: @David542 "gives me" how? If you just say `SELECT '20220101' INTO #table;`? Yes, I believe that's by design. T-SQL uses string delimiters for literals (not just dates but also for GUIDs). You can use variations on the ODBC syntax perhaps (`SELECT d = {ts '2022-01-01 15:19:36'} INTO #table;`), but yuck, why not just be explicit with `CONVERT` or use a variable with an explicit, intentional, self-documenting type declaration that will prevent future maintainers from wanting to hunt you down?

Comment: @David542 there is no SQL Server syntax to declare a literal of type date. You can use ODBC escape sequences to avoid a CAST but they still end up using a string literal in their definition and the resultant datatype is datetime not date even with `{d`

Comment: @David as you can see the column is date and the select returns also date not varchar

Comment: @nbk of course, I meant doing something like `SELECT date, '20220101' FROM t1`, the date col would be a date, and the 'literal' would be a string.

Comment: @David542 i added some more explanation, in your case sql doesn't need onvert the string as it isn't needed, but my added query that TSQL does it automatically